# What is the reason I'm seeing a Lookup index which is null when I run, graph.run(SHOW INDEXES;)?

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I'm relatively new to using neo4j. I've connected to a database with the py2neo library and populated the database with the faker library to create nodes for Person and Address each with attributes attached to them. I'm interested in creating indexes and testing the performance of different indexes. These were the two indexes I had created

```
`# Step 3: Create Indexes for Persons and Addresses
graph.run(" CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS FOR (p:Person) ON (p.name, p.dob, p.email, p.gender)")
graph.run("CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS FOR (a:Address) ON (a.address, a.postcode, a.country)")'
```

I created some indexes and used the command

```
`graph.run("SHOW INDEXES;")`
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Hw4J.png)

I was expecting 2 indexes to show but 3 indexes returned. The final one was a Look up type and had some null properties. That attached image shows the output, Why is this index showing up? Thanks.

I was expecting only 2 to return, so I'm thinking maybe this is some lack of understanding on my part? I've started reading through the Neo4j documentation on indexes but I'm still unsure. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience, neo4j creates 2 "lookup indexes" by default. (Not sure why you only saw one of them, but maybe the default indexes are only created when needed.)

According to the neo4j [operations manual](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/performance/index-configuration/):

> The token lookup index is the only index present by default in the
> database.

And the documentation also [states](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/performance/index-configuration/#index-configuration-token-lookup) that there are actually 2 such lookup indexes: 1 for node labels, and 1 for relationship types.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the additional index you're seeing is automatically created by Neo4j for internal use. Neo4j may create additional indexes to optimize its internal operations, and these indexes might not be directly created by users. In your case, the "Lookup" index that is showing null properties could be one of these internal indexes.

To confirm whether this index is indeed an internal index created by Neo4j, you can try querying the system catalogs directly. For example, you can use the following query to list all indexes in the database:

```
CALL db.indexes() YIELD description
RETURN description
```

Comment: Thanks for replying @Madhu Nathuram Kumawat. Yeah this is another issue I was running into. For some reason the call db.indexes() ... piece of code doesn't work. My Neo4j is version 5.12 so I don't think the version is the issue. Whenever I try it I'm met with the error of 

    There is no procedure with the name `db.indexes` registered for this database instance.

Comment: if db.indexes() isn't available in your Neo4j version, you can try using the db.indexes() function instead. This function can be used in a Cypher query to list all indexes in the database. Here's how you can use it:

'**CALL db.indexes() YIELD name, state, populationPercent, uniqueness, type, entityType, labelsOrTypes, properties

RETURN name, state, populationPercent, uniqueness, type, entityType, labelsOrTypes, properties **'

Hope this might help you!!